# Rendering human body in HTML

Tags: html

Are there examples of rendering images of the human body (front and back) using HTML?

We have an existing solution which uses JPG images, map, area and svg tags to render a human body and allow a user to hover the mouse cursors over them and choose an area.

The problem we have is that this effect seems to work fine in newer browsers, but for IE7, 8 and 9 the hover effect does not work at all.

We are open to looking at a different approach to doing this, gut I'm struggling to find any examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I were doing this I'd use regular image maps with a jQuery plugin called Image Mapster.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html

It allows you to use rollovers on image maps with alternate images as the rollover state.

Well worth a look.

There's a human skeleton demo already http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/joints/SkeletonJointExample.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've forwarded this onto my teammates. Looks promising.

Comment: ImageMapster worked a treat for us. Cheers :)